# How can I apply these textures to my model?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I bought a model (terrain model) that comes with these textures, but I don't know how to configure the nodes to apply the textures to the model (especially the mask texture).
[image]

Comment: A mask texture is usually used when combining images (of similar type), but since there is only a height and a single albedo, there doesn't seem to be anything there to mask in the first place. Did the model come with any additional textures, or any indication of what the mask is to be used for?

Comment: The *Color Space* value of the *height* Image Texture node should be set to *Non-Color*. What is the Mix Shader node for? (It makes no sense if you have only one slot plugged in ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should change the Color Space of the Height texture to "**Non-Color**" since you only have to use it to give height information for the material; basically black means "no height here", while white means "yes we have height here" and all the grey values in between mean "we have some degree of height here".

I don't think you need the mask map since it's not used on models but for mixing other materials usually.

The mix shader is useless in this case because you only have one shader (Diffuse).

Be sure to play with the **Strentgh** value of your bump node, 1 is usually too much so I'm pretty sure you wanna lower it.

If you have some other texture like specular and roughness you should substitute the diffuse node with a **Principled BSDF** so that you can connect them in the proper channel, they have to be set to "**Non-Color**" too by the way since,  like the height map, they don't give color information.

In the end you should have something like the image below, notice the Specular and Roughness channel on the Principled node.

[image]

I hope my answer helps you, if you have have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I understood perfectly, thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: Don't mention it, glad to help!